# Как вывести дату для каждого материала рубрики?

Tags: php, wordpress

Как вывести дату для каждого материала рубрики?делую следующее но выводится почему то только для одной записи а для остальных нет

```
 <?php if (have_posts()) : ?> 
            <?php
                $id=1; // ID заданной рубрики
                $n=3;   // количество выводимых записей
                $recent = new WP_Query("cat=$id&showposts=$n");
                while($recent->have_posts()) : $recent->the_post();
            ?>

<div class="bg4">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row border">
            <div class="col-sm-7">
                <div class="text">
                    <?php the_content(); ?>
                </div>
                <div class="data"><?php echo the_date('m.Y.d'); ?></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>          
            <?php endwhile;?>
                <div class="pagenavi"><?php if(function_exists('wp_pagenavi')) { wp_pagenavi(); } ?></div>
            <?php else : ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это происходит потому, что если в выборке есть несколько постов с одинаковой датой, то `the_date()` выведет дату только для первого из них.
Вместо функции `the_date()` используйте функцию `the_time()`:

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
    <?php
    $id=1; // ID заданной рубрики
    $n=3;   // количество выводимых записей
    $recent = new WP_Query("cat=$id&showposts=$n");
    while($recent->have_posts()) : $recent->the_post();
        ?>

        <div class="bg4">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row border">
                <div class="col-sm-7">
                    <div class="text">
                        <?php the_content(); ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="data"><?php the_time('m.Y.d'); ?></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php endwhile;?>
    <div class="pagenavi"><?php if(function_exists('wp_pagenavi')) { wp_pagenavi(); } ?></div>
<?php else : ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```